# Getting NullPointerException during merge of Collectors.toMap when merging to prevent duplicates

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am attempting to create a `Map<ProductKey, ProductDetail>` for a list of `Products` that need to have their `ProductDetail` added to them. The `ProductDetail` object is read from a database from a service `ProductDetailLookUpService`. I have not added the service because it needs a lot of exposure to internal info. Products may or may not have the `ProductDetail` and similar roducts may share the same ProductDetail.  Here are the basic classes that make up the relationships. However when I perform the merge I get a `NullPointerException`.

Here are the classes:

```java
@Data
static class ProductKey{
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long productCode;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long productDetailCode;
}

@Data
class Product {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private ProductKey productKey;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private ProductDetail productDetail;
}

@Data
class ProductDetail{
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long productCode;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String category;
}

public static Optional<ProductKey> findProductKey(Long productCode, List<ProductKey> productKeys) {
    return  productKeys.stream().
       filter(productKey -> productCode.equals(productKey.getProductCode()))
       .takeWhile(productKey -> productKey != null).findFirst();
}
```

Here is the code that populates the map from a question I had asked and for which a solution was so kindly provided: I added a filter to ensure the `productDetailMap` contains a matching `productKey.getProductCode()` so that all products with no matching `productCode` keys should be eliminated. I wasn't expecting any nulls to be in the final merge (left, right) -> left.

However, the error I get tells me that that is not the case:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1267) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$68(Collectors.java:1658) ~**[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]

```java
List<ProductKey> productKeyList = // initilizing the list
        
Map<Long, ProductDetail> productDetailMap = // initializing the map
        
Map<ProductKey, ProductDetail> prodDetailByKey = productKeyList.stream()
    .map(productKey ->
        findProductKey(productKey.getProductCode(), productKeyList)
    )
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .filter(productKey -> !productDetailMap.values().contains(productKey.getProductCode())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        productKey -> productDetailMap.get(productKey.getProductCode()),
        (left, right) -> left // precaution against duplicated elements in the productKeyList
    ));
```

In order to set the `ProductDetail` from the Map to the `Product` with the corresponding product key `Iterable.forEach()` would be more suitable than a stream.

```java
List<Product> products = service.readProducts();
    
products.forEach(product -> 
    product.setProductDetail(prodDetailByKey.get(product.getProductKey()))
);
```

Regarding the `null` Values, they can be easily eliminated from any Map:

```
productDetailMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: The nulls are occurring during the merge step, i.e. (left, right) -> left . I don't understanding how there could be nulls when there are no null keys in the map

Comment: Map returns null if the key is missing.